# How to generate line segments from survey records using PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, survey

I have a table of survey locations as

```
id,from,to,azimuth,x,y
'L1',0,5,120,508776,7098873
'L1',5,10,141,null,null
'L1',10,24,121,null,null
'L2',0,12,135,507882,8020098 
'L2',12,15,121,null,null
'L2',15,25,null,null
```

Each line "id" can have 2 or more records defining their geometry.

Using a postgis query, how can I create line segments for each of these records, assuming the x and y values for the line starts are in EPSG:3578?
I've tried LAG and LEAD OVER (Partition BY "id" order by "from_m"), but I get lost in the recursion needed. Is what I'm attempting possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the whole table the database will run the LAG/LEAD OVER for every selected row. You can return a new column with the result. I think this is already the recursion you need.

I once did this with time based positions and created a line from the temporal latest point to his ancestor. I ordered by time - in your case you need to order by 'from' or 'to'. Sometimes running an independent query for every id is easier than doing the whole thing at once.

Have a look at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174426/get-the-2-points-immediately-before-and-after-a-given-point-in-postgis), they are trying pretty much the opposite of what you want, but maybe it will help you clarify things.

Comment: Thank you. Only "start" survey points have coordinates from which to calculate. Every other survey segment needs to get its start point by walking the array of "previous" survey line segments to arrive at the correct position for its start position.